# Как по клику на другие элементы списка удалять класс у блока

Tags: jquery

Есть список. При нажатии на 1 пункт блоку, находящемуся не в этом списке, присваивается класс. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на другой элемент списка класс удалялся? Как отследить нажатие на другой элемент списка?

Для примера:

```
$(".SUBARU").click(function() {
    $(".SUBARU1").addClass("on");
});
```

Надо чтобы при клике на какой-либо другой элемент списка было `removeClass("on")`.

Comment: Да что же у всех в интернете символы-то платные. Экономят на всём - даже единичку не могут словами написать. Вот в данном конкретном случае, @Дима, у Вас имелось ввиду "первый" или "один"? И код html приведите всё-таки

Comment: @АлександрБелинский без примера HTML тут, в принципе, обойтись можно (хватает описания словами), а вот с `1` действительно приходится догадываться. Вот будет "неловко", если я зря расписывал варианты с _первым_ пунктом.

Comment: Кстати, если в вопросе имелось ввиду просто-напросто "как селектором указать все элементы класса, кроме первого", то вот чудесный ответ - [варианты на любой вкус](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2259397/8737307). К тому же, интуитивно понятно и легко читается.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("li").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('li').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
li{cursor:pointer}
.active{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
  <li>Point</li>
</ul>
```

1. Берём элемент `<li>`, при щелчке по элементу вызываем функцию `($("li").click(function())`
2. Берём этот же элемент, по которому был щелчок, и добавляем ему класс. `$(this).addClass('active');`
3. Дальше берём все элементы `<li>` кроме того, по которому был щелчок, с помощю функции [.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) и удаляем остальным класс (`active`).

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно на первый элемент повесить один обработчик, в котором класс `on` добавляется, а на все остальные повесить другой обработчик, в котором этот класс удаляется:

```js
var $subaru = $(".SUBARU");
$subaru.eq(0).on("click", function() {
    $(".SUBARU1").addClass("on");
});
$subaru.not(":first").on("click", function() {
    $(".SUBARU1").removeClass("on");
});
```

```css
.on {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="SUBARU">Первый</li>
  <li class="SUBARU">Второй</li>
  <li class="SUBARU">Третий</li>
</ul>
<div class="SUBARU1">Блок вне списка</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Также можно оставить один обработчик события, внутри которого вычислять индекс кликнутого элемента и принимать по значению этого индекса решение о добавлении/удалении класса:

```js
var $subaru = $(".SUBARU");
$subaru.on("click", function() {
    var index = $subaru.index(this);
    $(".SUBARU1").toggleClass("on", index == 0);
});
```

```css
.on {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="SUBARU">Первый</li>
  <li class="SUBARU">Второй</li>
  <li class="SUBARU">Третий</li>
</ul>
<div class="SUBARU1">Блок вне списка</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

А ещё индекс можно не вычислять каждый раз, а сохранять сразу в обработчике при добавлении каждому элементу списка своего обработчика:

```js
$(".SUBARU").each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
    $(".SUBARU1").toggleClass("on", index == 0);
  });
});
```

```css
.on {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="SUBARU">Первый</li>
  <li class="SUBARU">Второй</li>
  <li class="SUBARU">Третий</li>
</ul>
<div class="SUBARU1">Блок вне списка</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Но это уже, что называется, "на любителя".

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".SUBARU:first-child").click(function() {
  $(".SUBARU1").addClass("on");
});
$(".SUBARU:not(:first-child)").click(function() {
  $(".SUBARU1").removeClass("on");
});
```

Comment: Ваш ответ попал в очередь некачественных ответов. Не могли бы описать основную применённую идею?